# For Loop - Reading in all excel tabs into Panda Df's

Tags: excel, pandas, loops, import-from-excel

I have an .xlsx book and I would like to write a function or loop that would create Panda(s) DF's for each tab in excel. So for example, let's say that I have an excel book called book.xlsx and tabs called sheet1 - sheet6. I would like to read in the excel file and create 6 Panda DF's (sheet1 - sheet6) from a function or loop?

Answer (score 0):

To load the file:

```py
path = '../files_to_load/my_file.xlsx'
print(path)
excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(path)
print('File uploaded ✔')
```

To get a specific sheet:

```py
# Get a specific sheet
raw_data = excel_file.parse('sheet1')
```

#### Here an example for the Loop:

You will have all of you sheets stored in a list. All the sheets will be dataframes

```py
In [1]:
import pandas as pd

path = 'my_path/my_file.xlsx'
excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(path)

sheets = []
for sheet in excel_file.sheet_names:
    data = excel_file.parse(sheet)
    sheets.append(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `sheet_name` argument to `None` - it would create an ordered dictionary of sheets stored as dataframes.

```py
dataframes = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=None)
```

---

```py
>>> type(dataframes)
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>
>>> type(dataframes['first']) # `first` is the name a sheet
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```